# Маска подсети

Tags: ip

как создается маска подсети?Ну вот я понял как с помощью маски и ip-адреса можно вычислить адрес сети, но не могу понять откуда таблица получает маску и как она вычисляется?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вы говорите об [этом](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR#.D0.92.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8).